# Jquery function is not working on AJAX loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Don't throw rocks at me. I asked something very similar not so long ago but this is different. Now I know that I have to delegate event to make them work on newly loaded element. But what if there is no event to delegate, but a function that need to use the new elements?

Let's suppose it is this one:

```
function fixHeight (x) {    
    $(".test").height(x);
};
```

Now every time I load the content that has some elements with the class ".test", that functions runs, but it won't affects the new elements.

```
$.get( url, function(data){
    //some code that inserts the data retrieved in an already existing element
    fixHeight (x);

}).fail(function() {
    //fallback code
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Post the code where and when you are calling this function `fixHeight`?

Comment: The code is kind of long, and not necesary here. The function is called after the content is retrieved and inserted in an already existing element. I'm adding a little example. Thanks

Comment: Your `fixHeight()` function will definitely affect *all* elements that match the `".test"` selector at the time it is called, which would include any new elements added in your `$.get()` callback just before you call it. Perhaps there is some mistake in the way you add the elements such that they don't have that class - I don't think we can help unless you show that code.

Comment: The code that was shown above looks good. Only way why its not working could be due to a javascript error in one of the above lines before calling the function. Can you look at the console for any errors or Can you able to create a working example to reproduce the issue using stack snippet (or) jsfiddle (or) plunker ?

Comment: There are not any errors in the console, but i think i've might had found the problem. brb

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would cause the problem you've described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. There is an animation in a plugin i made that delays the change of the content a little, for which the ajax loaded elements were inserted a little after the function ran.
Thanks for your answers, i thought it was a similar problem to the one i had with the events but it was a brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

Call the function **after** you append the element to the `DOM`

Comment: Of course I'm calling the function after, Algorithms 101. I added a little piece of code to make it more clear that I'm in fact calling the function AFTER the elements are appended to the DOM. Thanks!

Comment: then that means you either have a wrong selector for selecting the element or you have some other errors on the page